# Changing options in select based from country

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have an add customer page with 2 selects (Country and City). When I choose  `Country` and choose `USA`, the 2nd select will have the options of cities in USA.  If I choose `Philippines` the options will be the cities in the Philippines, same with `Canada`, etc.

My Code is like this:

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" required>
          <option selected disabled>*Select Country </option>
          <option>USA</option>
          <option>Philippines</option>
          <option>Canada</option>

</select> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

       //If 'USA' was selected the select options values will be this like.

        <select class="form-control" name="loc" required>
          <option selected disabled>*State / City</option>
          <option></option>
          <option>California</option>
          <option>New York</option>
          <option>New Jersey</option>
          <option>Illinois</option>
          <option>Others</option>
        </select>

     //else If 'Philippines' was selected the select options values will be this like.

        <select class="form-control" name="loc" required>
           <option selected disabled>*State / City</option>
          <option></option>
          <option>Manila</option>
          <option>Quezon City</option>
          <option>Makati</option>
          <option>Cebu</option>
          <option>Davao</option>
          <option>Others</option>



     //else If 'Canada' was selected the select options values will be this like.

        <select class="form-control" name="loc" required>
           <option selected disabled>*State / City</option>
          <option></option>
          <option>Toronto</option>
          <option>Vancouver</option>
          <option>Others</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: Are they stored in your MySQL database? Or are they fix? If yes, can you give us your table structure.

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery? Also, none of your options have values `<option value="USA">USA</option>`?  Lastly, how many countries are you intending to support? (There are many, and thousands of potential cities).

Comment: @cale_b actually is that was only the cities I want to use.

Comment: @Edmhar chech this fiddle this will help http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/8Lcq62mn/16/

Comment: @Pekka how can I get the value so I can add this to mySQL.

Comment: @Edmhar are you adding select option dynamically?how are you pulling your data from database

Comment: @Edmhar - what is your table structure? And how is your `country` table connected to your `city` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to easily achieve what you want, you can use jQuery which you can download [here](https://jquery.com/download/).

Then I added `id` tags for your `<select>` fields and `value` tags for your options.

```
<select class="form-control" name="country" id="country" required>
  <option selected disabled>*Select Country </option>
  <option option="USA">USA</option>
  <option option="Philippines">Philippines</option>
  <option option="Canada">Canada</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="loc" id="loc" required>
<!-- REST OF OTHER CODES -->
```

Then create the script:

```
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script><!-- REPLACE NECESSARY JQUERY FILE DEPENDING ON THE VERSION YOU HAVE DOWNLOADED -->

<!-- START CREATING YOUR SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#country").change(function(){
       var country = $(this).val();
       var usa = '<option>California</option><option>New York</option><option>New Jersey</option><option>Illinois</option><option>Others</option>';
       var phi = '<option>Manila</option><option>Quezon City</option><option>Makati</option><option>Cebu</option><option>Davao</option><option>Others</option>';
       var can = '<option>Toronto</option><option>Vancouver</option>'; 
       var other = '<option selected disabled>*State / City</option>';

       if(country == "USA"){
         $("#loc").empty().append(usa);
       }
       else if(country == "Philippines"){
         $("#loc").empty().append(phi);
       }
       else if(country == "Canada"){
         $("#loc").empty().append(can);
       }
       else {
         $("#loc").empty().append(other);  
       }
    });

  });

</script>
```

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Logan_Wayne/n3eo97Ln/).

I have to scrap my first answer knowing that your form is a static one.

Answer (score 1):

The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f1q740dg/) you have shown works fine. Just include this line in your `<head>` tags...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

NOTE: Scrapped original answer based on OP comments.

Comment: Kuya one question out of curiosity is it advisable to put php script on html page ?

Comment: Yes, it's perfectly acceptable and even sometimes required to achieve the output desired.

Comment: ty kuya for clarification..happy coding

Comment: Kumusta @Kuya, Actually I'm not pulling out City or Country from database. I'm actually inserting. Salamat!

Comment: Who is inserting... You? or your Visitors?

Comment: All i want was responsive 'Country' dropdown select so if I choose PH the second dropdown will show the Manila, Makati and Quezon City.

Comment: @Edmhar so the value of selection option is static?you can go with the fiddle i showed you

Comment: Then you will have to hard code everything and use jQuery

Comment: @Kuya Yes, That's why I'm doing right now but it seems something wrong hehe.

Comment: set a parent id for each city then after change of country select all option in city with parent id matching the current country id and show then hide everything else

Comment: I know that you are inputting your own countries and cities in a static method; however, if I were you (since you're doing it anyway) why not insert them into a database table? Then they will always be there for future use. (If the project you are currently working on has the ability to use databases). It will save you any additional work in the future. Just a thought.

Comment: @Kuya Can I message you sir?

Comment: SO doesn't have a message feature.

Comment: I have the DB structure for the code I provided above based on the info you provided in your question. Kasi, I never supply an answer before I test the code to make sure it works as expected.

Comment: @Kuya I see, I have here the codes of the select. But still error, I don't know what's wrong.
http://jsfiddle.net/f1q740dg/

Comment: you didnt include the jquery script it says $ undefined

Comment: In your fiddle you had it set as straight javascript. It is actually jQuery. You need to include jQuery by changing `no library (pure JS)` to `jQuery 2.1.3` underneath "Frameworks & Extensions" in the upper left. Then it will work.

Comment: Thank you Kuya! Maraming Salamat!